# Approximate Periodic Function by shifting Basis Functions

Tags: optimization, approximation, signal-processing, periodic-functions

[image: Plot]

Given

- a periodic "Target Function" $F(t)$
- a set of $N$ periodic "Basis Functions"
  $B_i(t)$ of arbitrary shape

All functions are defined on the same interval $T$.

I am allowed to shift the basis functions individually by a constant value of $t_i$.
$$
B_i'(t,t_i) = B_i(t-t_i).
$$
I want to approximate $F(t)$ with the function

$$
A(t,t_1..t_N) = \sum\limits_{i=1}^N B_i'(t,t_i).
$$

How can I efficiently find the values $t_1..t_n$ that minimize the difference between $A(t)$ and $F(t)$?

$$
\min\int_0^T \! (F(t)-A(t,t_1..t_N))^2 \, \mathrm{d}t. 
$$

PS: I'm using a discrete t axis. So the integral could be rewritten as a sum.

Comment: Could you please define $B_i(t)$ and $F(t)$? It should be made clear to define how $\int F(t)B_i(t)dt$ depends on the $t_i$.

Comment: I added the $t_i$ to the parameters of $A$ to make the dependency clear.

Comment: This does not answer my question. For the minimization, it is necessary to know how $\int F(t)B_i(t-t_i)dt$ depends on $t_i$.

Comment: Introduced $B'(t)$. $B(t)$ is not dependent on $t_i$ but $B_i'(t,t_i)$ is by definition. Also, please note that the term inside the integral is a squared difference, not a product.

Comment: Without anymore specificity, all I can suggest is a Nelder-Mead simplex-style search that will try to estimate the cost surface numerically and follow it down.

Comment: With the problem stated in its current form, I don't believe a non-brute-force method exists.  Some additional knowledge about the $B_i \left( t \right)$ basis functions and/or target function $F \left( t \right)$ may yield a more efficient algorithm.

Comment: Agreed. Because the amplitude of each basis function is fixed, this is almost certainly intractable. For the discrete case, if there are $M$ discrete points in the time domain, there are $M^N$ possible solutions.

Comment: In your example, the basis functions are 1) piecewise constant or linear, 2) non-overlapping (when the solution is achieved), 3) perfectly reconstruct $F$. Is that always the case or just incidental ? And do you confirm that only sums are allowed, not linear combinations ?

Comment: All 3 are points are just incidental, should have made a more general sample plot. Although for 1, since I use sampled signals, they could be seen as piecewise constant.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use normalized cross correlation with each basis function. If the normalization is with respect to the support of each basis function then you will find the best shift to fit each basis function to the function of interest (classical needle in the haystack problem). This can be accomplished in the transform domain - and exploits the Fourier transform shift theorem.

If the basis functions are intended to stack up horizontally in a mutually (temporally) orthogonal fashion (as shown in your picture) then the shift theorem in combination with the Plancherel theorem (to support the orthogonal annihilation of the cross terms) gives

$t_i = -arg(\frac{\hat{F}(\xi)}{\hat{B}_i(\xi)})/(2 \pi \xi)$ for any particular $\xi$ and $\hat{B}_i(\xi)$ is the Fourier transform of the $ith$ un-shifted basis function. This solution does minimize your data discrepancy functional $\int_0^T \! (F(t)-A(t,t_1..t_N))^2 \, \mathrm{d}t$.

Additionally - you mentioned that your functions are periodic - this means that they have a Fourier series - and that simplifies things quite a lot. Also - because your data are discrete - you can use the FFT to solve the problem. You should be able to do it using the first mode (k=1).